# Necessitare di/aver bisogno di?

Tags: verbs, grammar, prepositions

1. Necessito di una stanza.
2. Necessito di stare tranquillo.
3. Ho/c'è bisogno di questo.
4. Ho/c'è bisogno di fare questo.

Avrei detto "complementi di specificazione" pensando alla combinazione "sostantivo+preposizione", ma pensando che le suddette costruzioni reggono anche implicite ed esplicite, mi viene il dubbio che mi stia sbagliando.

Cercando in rete non ho trovato nulla a riguardo.

Come si potrebbero classificare costrutti del genere?

Comment: Non ho mai capito il senso di classificare i complementi. Si trovano simili classificazioni arbitrarie di ogni tipo e di nessuna utilità. Picchiato da me --> complemento di agente. Picchiato dal vento --> complemento di causa efficiente. Picchiato da mezz'ora --> complemento di durata delle botte. Mah!

Comment: @MauroVanetti: Nel complesso sono d'accordo con te, ma non sono del tutto campati in aria; un'utilità ce l'hanno, ed è nello studio delle lingue classiche. Nell'esempio che fai, in latino il complemento di agente si esprime in un modo (_a/ab_ + ablativo) e quello di causa efficiente in un altro (ablativo da solo). Certo, se è solo per parlare dell'italiano si potrebbe quanto meno ridurre il numero di complementi diversi da considerare, o usare altri approcci, come quello della linguistica valenziale.

Comment: Ma proprio il fatto che complementi che in una lingua sono indistinguibili in un'altra si dicono diversamente e viceversa a me fa pensare che invece di parlare di complementi con tutta una loro impossibile tassonomia arbitraria si dovrebbe semplicemente imparare quali sono le funzioni semantiche delle varie preposizioni e/o dei vari casi in ciascuna lingua.

Answer (score 0):

Io la vedrei come un'oggettiva, dato che esprimono una necessita' reale e entrambi i verbi reggono sia esplicite che implicite.